# Canvas with mousemove blocking links in div underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, draw, mousemove

I'm having problems with using the canvas/mousemove. I want to be able to draw on the entire page whenever the mouse moves with a mousemove draw/paint tool but also still click text links that appear in various other divs. The issue I have is that the canvas which is currently fixed, has a transparent background color and is set to 100% width and height blocks the div underneath with a lower z-index, meaning the links can't be clicked. Using pointer-events:none on the canvas isn't the solution as it disables the mousemove effect. If I make the canvas z-index lower than the div's with the links I want to click, the drawing will just appear outside of the div.

What do I need to add or change to make this work? I basically just want to have a functioning webpage with a mouseover effect that will draw over the page whenever it moves.

Below is the script I'm using. And here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/zAF4d/1/

```
$(function() {
var letsdraw = false;

var theCanvas = document.getElementById('paint');
var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
theCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
theCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var canvasOffset = $('#paint').offset();

$('#paint').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (letsdraw === true) {
        ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});

$('#paint').mousemove(function(e) {
$('.v').css('left', e.clientX + 'px');
$('.h').css('top', e.clientY + 'px');
    letsdraw = true;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
});

$(window).mouseout(function(e) {
    // bind to the window mouse up, that way if you mouse up and you're not over 
    // the canvas you'll still get the release of the drawing.
    letsdraw = true;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> The issue I have is that the canvas which is currently fixed, has a transparent background color and is set to 100% width and height blocks the div underneath with a lower z-index, meaning the links can't be clicked. Using pointer-events:none on the canvas isn't the solution as it disables the mousemove effect. If I make the canvas z-index lower than the div's with the links I want to click, the drawing will just appear outside of the div.

I think you need to either do everything on canvas or use DOM and some sort of CSS tricks/animations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
var letsdraw = false;

var theCanvas = document.getElementById('paint');
var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

.
.
.
**//if your div's are not same every time, determine similar prop so u can pull it here on to a canvas...by'ID' || 'Class' ...etc.**

```
var div = document.getElementByID('div01');
dix.x;
div.y;
div.h;
```

.
.
.

**etc. or if u cannot for any reason pull actual div, just pass on it parameters here....
then u can use them here...*

**like making collision model for drawing line over the top of it...**

```
if (mouse.x > div.x && mouse.x < div.x + div.width && mouse.y > div.y && mouse.y < div.height) {
letsdraw = false;
}
```

....**within draw function

**'onclick' event listener try  **

```
$(div)onclick function();
```

**if whole div was pulled here then it will open links...but even if u pulled just div's parameters u just pass click coordinates on to div if link coordinates match**

```
$(div)onclick function(){
load.page(url: <link>your link</>
}
```

**sorry if mistaken something, didn't run it all together**

But give it a go hope it helps;